# Pasar una variable de javascript a php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Llevo mucho tiempo tratando de hacer un buscador en el que se puedan pinchar en los resultados. Ahora, por fin lo he conseguido, pero aquí es donde empieza el principal problema. Cuando se pulsa en el resultado, se obtiene el value de dicho resultado(botón), que se almacena en la variable IDbutton en javascript). Pero después me gustaría convertirla (usarla) en php para utilizarla en una consulta a mysql. Pero no consigo pasar la variable de javascript a php. He tratado de hacerlo con ajax y me resulta casi imposible, ya que necesito dos archivos y yo solo quiero utilizar uno (es decir, todos los códigos están en el mismo archivo). Si alguien sabe otro modo o me explica mejor como enviarla por ajax lo agradecería.

Este es el código html del buscador (tiene una estructura más compleja detrás pero es inecesaria para este problema):

```
<h1>Buscador de grupos</h1>
  <div class="form-1-2">
   <label for="buscador">Buscar:</label>
   <input type="search" name="buscador" id="buscador"></input>
 </div>
<div class="datos" id="datos">
</div>
```

Este es el código del botón en el que se pulsa:

```
<button value='{$fila['numero']}' class=button_buscar_user>{$fila['nombre']}</button>
```

Y este es el código que se activa cuando se pulsa en los resultados:

```
<script>
$('body').on('click' , '.button_buscar_user' , function() { 
var IDbutton = $(this).val();
document.getElementById('rightCounter13').innerHTML = rightAnswers;
document.getElementById('wrongCounter13').innerHTML = wrongAnswers;
modal_container2_4.classList.add('show2');
})
</script>
```

Y me gustaría un código php como el siguiente, en el que $IDbutton fuera la variable IDbutton de antes en javascript:

```
<?php echo $IDbutton;?>
```

Comment: **No puedes hacerlo con un solo archivo**. La idea de Ajax es poder intercambiar datos entre el cliente (Javascript) y el servidor (PHP) sin necesidad de recargar la página. Para eso necesitas tener un archivo donde estaría el código Ajax (lado del cliente) y **otro archivo distinto** que pondrías en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax (lado del servidor), el cual es el encargado de recibir/procesar los datos en el servidor y devolver una respuesta de nuevo al cliente si fuera preciso. Si no tienes eso claro no has entendido Ajax y pronto te encontrarás perdido en tu propio código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que usar AJAX, teniendo en cuenta que usas JQuery yo lo haría de la siguiente manera:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'ejemplo.php', //<- insertas la ruta del archivo .php done hará la consulta
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            id: tu_id // <- insertas la id
        },
        success: function (result){
          //Aquí entrara cuando reciba los datos del .php
        }
    });
```

Y luego creas el archivo .php, obtienes los datos, haces la consulta y envías los datos que quieras.

```
$dblink=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","TuUsuario","TuContraseña","TuDB") or exit(mysqli_connect_error());

//Aquí obtienes la id y la almacenamos en una variable
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; /

//Hacemos la consulta
$sql="SELECT * FROM notas WHERE id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($dblink, $sql);

// y ahora solo tienes que hacer un echo con los datos que quieras recibir en tu js.
```